# System.DmlException when inserting account records in a loop

Tags: apex

I have a problem with the code below giving me the following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   0030Y00000TpxVuQAJ; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE,
>   cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

```
@testSetup
static void setUp(){
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    String billingState = 'NY';
    for(Integer i=0; i<2; i++){
        accList.add(new Account(Name='TestAccountABC ' + i, BillingState = billingState));
    }
    insert accList;
}
```

I have a similar `setUp()` class that I use to make leads for a different test class that works the same way(for loop that adds new leads to list that I insert after the loop) but that one works. So I am wondering what mistake I am doing in my code and a way to fix it.

Thank you!

EDIT: As was pointed out the code above is actually fine. Since Stack Trace for the error gave me the row where my  `setUp()` class was inserting records I assumed the error was there. Thank you to the both of you manjit_singh and NITHESH K for helping me figure it out.

Comment: i have tried  your code, its working fine. Nothing Found any error in that.

Comment: Can you add more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your error closely it says that the error is not while inserting `Account` but while inserting `Contact`.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id **0030Y00000TpxVuQAJ**; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

`003` is SFDC prefix for a Contact. So the error is not in the code you posted but somewhere else. Somewhere where you are inserting the contact.

**Cause:**

It looks like that you are specifying an `ID` while inserting a record which is not allowed by SFDC.

Since you are inserting and Account and assuming you are inserting contact as well. Just make sure you have not done this accidentally.

`con.Id = acc.Id`